# How to take a complex integral?

Tags: complex-integration

I wish to understand how to take complex integrals and derivatives.

For the simplest case, $\int{x+iy, dz}$

$f(z) dz = (u + iv)(dx + idy) = (u + iv) dx + (iu − v) dy
= (udx − vdy) + i(vdx + udy)$

So
$\int({x+iy})(dx+idy)$
$=(\int{xdx}-\int ydy)+i(\int ydx+\int xdy)$
$=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}+2xyi$

Did I do it right?

Answer (score 1):

Almost, you have $2xyi$ instead of $xyi$. You can also see that as $$\int z\,{\rm d}z = \frac{z^2}{2},$$since $$\frac{(x+iy)^2}{2} = \frac{x^2-y^2}{2} + xyi.$$

Comment: When integrating are there any times that I cannot treat the complex variable like a regular variable?

Comment: Not that I recall.